# Does the Fujifilm X-Pro 1 show the effects of exposure compensation in the EVF?

Tags: fujifilm, fujifilm-xpro1, exposure-compensation, evf

This is something I never noticed while I had my hands on the X-Pro 1 — maybe because I didn't use the EVF mode as much as the optical finder, or maybe because I wasn't in situations where exposure compensation was really called for. However, I'm by the water in the sun with the Olympus OM-D E-M5, and I noticed that I could easily see that the default metering was underexposing my subject — and that when I dialed in compensation, the effect was immediately visible in the EVF.

Does the X-Pro 1 do this too, and I just didn't notice? I'm new to the EVF world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I asked this in 2012, the answer was "no". However, a firmware update in December 2014 changed it to "there's a setting for that — but only in manual mode". This is also the case in newer X-series cameras like the X-T2 or X-Pro 2. There are two settings:

- `PREVIEW EXP./WB IN MANUAL MODE`
- `PREVIEW PIC. EFFECT`

The first shows the effect of exposure in the viewfinder, but as noted, only in manual mode. It does not work with exposure compensation in aperture or shutter priority, or in full automatic. That's unfortunate, but at least still somewhat useful.

The second setting affects all modes and shows film simulation modes as selected — very nice for shooting in black and white!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I have been able to determine, the only exposure compensation indications in the X-Pro 1's EVF are on the histogram overlay and the exposure meter; the actual viewfinder image stays at the "correct" exposure. See [the viewfinder page of the DPReview review](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/fujifilm-x-pro1/10); it has a viewfinder image graphic that shows what everyone else seems to be saying in text. In manual exposure mode, you get even less help.

It could be argued, though, that the viewfinder is doing electronically what you'd expect an optical viewfinder to do, giving you a usable viewfinder image regardless of the metering selected. (Most of the EVFs I've used over the years, going back to the Minolta Dimage and early Fuji superzooms have worked this way.) Either choice works; it's all a matter of the photographer's exectations.

Comment: Yeah, I agree — the priority in the X-Pro is clearly to enable the magic thing where you hit the EVF/optical switch and get roughly the same view. Changing exposure wouldn't fit that design choice. Still, shame that it isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

No. The Fuji X-Pro1 is not *Exposure-Priority*, so it does not simulate exposure.

This one observation in my [review of the X-Pro1](http://www.neocamera.com/camera/fuji/xpro1/review), just published a few days ago. Things get worse in Manual mode because the histogram does not change either since it is based on the display.

This is really too bad as one of the best things an EVF can do is preview exposure. Some cameras from Minolta and then Sony had an option or switch to control if exposure is previewed or not. One way that Fuji cameras used to work which was a reasonable compromise is that they normally showed a bright image and when the shutter is pressed halfway, the simulated exposure was shown. The Canon G1 X does this with its LCD.